# Existence of an extreme point for a bounded closed convex subset of $B(\ell^p)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

For $1\leq p \leq \infty$ let $B(\ell^p)$ denotes the Banach space of all bounded linear operators on $\ell^p.$ Suppose that $A$ is a bounded closed convex subset of $B(\ell^p)$. Does $A$ possess an extreme point (for some  $1\leq p \leq \infty$)?

Comment: For a Hilbert space H, isometries are extreme points of the closed unit ball of $B(H)$, and the closed unit ball is the closed convex hull of its extreme points.  The latter follows from a combination of Banach-Alaoglu theorem and Krein-Milman theorem along with $B(H)$ being the Banach-space dual of the trace-class operators.

Comment: Thank you, John.  If $A\subseteq B(\ell^2)$ is non-empty closed and convex subset, then can we use from your mentioned theorems to say that $A$ has an extreme point?

Comment: I don't think so, because a bounded non-empty closed convex set doesn't have to be closed in the weak$^*$ topology.  $B(H)$ is not a reflexive Banach space.

Comment: PS correction, should have said - the closed unit ball is the *weak$^*$-closed* convex hull of its extreme points.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  Let $c_0$ be the space of all sequences vanishing at infinity with $\sup$ norm.  $c_0$ is isometrically embedded into $B(l^p)$ as multiplication operators.  Let $V$ be the closed unit ball of $c_0$.  Then $V$ is non-empty and convex.  $V$ is a closed subset of $c_0$ and $c_0$ is a complete metric space, so $c_0$ is a closed subset of $B(l^p)$.  Therefore $V$ is a closed subset of $B(l^p)$.  Also, $V$ is bounded in norm by $1$.

$V$ does not have extreme points.  If $\vec{a}=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in V$ then $|a_n|\le 1$ for all $n$, and $|a_m| < 1$ for at least some $m$ (since the sequence converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.)  Let $\vec{e}_m$ be the standard basis vector in coordinate $m$.  Then $\vec{a}=((\vec{a}+\varepsilon \vec{e}_m) + (\vec{a}-\varepsilon \vec{e}_m))/2$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ and the non-trivial convex combination is in $V$.

To see that $c_0$ is embedded isometrically in $B(l^p)$, let $\vec{a}=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in c_0$ and $\vec{b}=\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in l^p$.  Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n b_n|^p \le (\|\vec{a}\|_\infty)^p \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^p$$
where $\|\vec{a}\|_\infty=\sup_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$.  So $\|M_{\vec{a}} \vec{b}\|_p\le \|\vec{a}\|_\infty \|\vec{b}\|_p$, where $M_{\vec{a}}$ denotes the multiplication by $\vec{a}$ operator.  This shows $\|M_{\vec{a}}\| \le \|\vec{a}\|_\infty$ where $\|M_{\vec{a}}\|$ is the operator norm.

To see that $\|M_{\vec{a}}\|$ is exactly $\|\vec{a}\|_\infty$, apply $M_{\vec{a}}$ to the basis vectors $\vec{e}_n$.
$$M_{\vec{a}} \vec{e}_n = a_n e_n$$
so $\|M_{\vec{a}} \vec{e}_n\|_p = |a_n|\le \|M_{\vec{a}}\|\|\vec{e}_n\|_p = \|M_{\vec{a}}\|$.  This is for all $n$ so $\|\vec{a}\|_\infty \le \|M_{\vec{a}}\|$